# vuex: unknown getter: user

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm experimenting with vuex and I was looking for best way to organize my vuex files I finished with something like this:

/src/store/user/state.js:

```
export default {
  state: {
    user: null
  }
}
```

/src/store/user/getters.js:

```
export default {
  getters: {
    user (state) {
      return state.user
    }
  }
}
```

/src/store/user/mutations.js:

```
export default {
  mutations: {
    'SET_USER' (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  }
}
```

/src/store/user/actions.js

```
export default {
  actions: {
    loginUser ({ commit }, params) {
       commit('SET_USER', {id: 1})
    }
  }
}
```

/src/store/user/index.js

```
import state from './state'
import getters from './getters'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

/src/store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './user'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
})
```

When I load my code it returns in console following error:

```
vuex: unknown getter: user
```

Comment: what do you have in src/store/user?

Comment: In src/store/user I have 5 files: state.js, getters.js, mutations.js, actions.js and index.js. Content of theese files are in question.

Comment: In your /src/store/index.js:you are importing user module. The module path should be './user/index' right. , because you are exporting state, getters, mutations, actions in /src/store/user/index.js.

Comment: It does not matter, If write it like: ./user vue will automatically import index.js file, it is just a shortcut so this is not a problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each of your user-related files are using `export default`, which means when you import those files, you are naming the entire object being exported `state`, `getters`, etc.

So, in the scope of `index`, the `state` variable has a property named `state`, the `getters` variable has a property named `getters`, etc. And this is throwing things off.

You should export a `const` for each of these files instead:

```
export const state = {
  user: null,
}
```

And then when importing grab the named `const` like so:

```
import { state } from './state'
```

---

Alternatively, you could just remove the properties for `state`, `getters`, etc. from each file:

```
// state.js
export default {
  user: null,
}
```

And then import like you're doing already:

```
import state from './state'
```

Comment: I do it in this way. Now when I run my app I see in console following warning:

```./src/store/user/index.js
7:9-14 "export 'default' (imported as 'state') was not found in './state'
./src/store/user/index.js
8:11-18 "export 'default' (imported as 'getters') was not found in './getters'
./src/store/user/index.js
9:11-18 "export 'default' (imported as 'actions') was not found in './actions'
./src/store/user/index.js
10:13-22 "export 'default' (imported as 'mutations') was not found in './mutations'```

Comment: I changed my imports in store/user/index.js to look like this:

```import { state } from './state'``` and everything works. Thank You very much.